# How to fix the sending of errors to frontend from apollo server

Tags: reactjs, apollo

I'm trying to make a registration form with Apollo and React and I'm facing a problem with handling the errors after request.

The problem occurs in such way: When I try to register user which already exists I get an error in console  `That username is already in use!` but the error which my server sends is

```
GraphQL error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation.registerUser.
```

This happens when I try to return something only on success.

If I try to return something either way I get the error on console but frontend receives it as a success and the next logic occurs (in my case redirect to another page)

What I'm trying to figure out is how to send the right error message to the frontend? Because right no all the errors are being thrown on the backend and I see them only in my console but Apollo sends defferent errors.

This is the code I have

*typeDefs.ts*

```
module.exports = gql`
  type Response {
    message: String!
  }
  input RegisterInput {
    username: String!
    password: String!
  }
  type Mutation {
    registerUser(registerInput: RegisterInput): Response!
  }
`;
```

*mutation on frontend*

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const REGISTER_USER = gql`
  mutation RegisterUser($registerInput: RegisterInput) {
    registerUser(registerInput: $registerInput) {
      message
    }
  }
`;

export { REGISTER_USER };
```

mutation on backend

```
Mutation: {
    registerUser(_, { registerInput }) {
      const { username, password } = registerInput;
      const saltRounds = 12;

      console.log(123);

      if (!username || !password) {
        throw new Error('Username and password are required!');
      }
      if (password.length < 6) {
        throw new Error('Password must be minimum 6 characters!');
      }

      UserModel.findOne({ username }, (error: string, existingUser: User) => {
        if (error) {
          throw new Error(error);
        }
        if (existingUser) {
          throw new Error('That username is already in use!');
        } else if (!error && !existingUser) {
          bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, (error: string, salt: string) => {
            if (error) {
              throw new Error(error);
            }
            bcrypt.hash(password, salt, (error: string, hash: string) => {
              if (error) {
                throw new Error(error);
              } else {
                const newUser = new UserModel({
                  username,
                  password: hash,
                });

                newUser.save((error: string, user: User) => {
                  if (error) {
                    throw new Error(error);
                  } else {
                    return {
                      message: 'Registered successfully',
                    };
                  }
                });
              }
            });
          });
        }
      });
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding doing this:

```
type SuccessRespose {
    message: String!
  }

type Mutation {
    registerUser(registerInput: RegisterInput): SuccessRespose!
  }
```

in resolvers

```
const user = await UserModel.findOne(
        { username },
        (error: string, existingUser: User): void => {
          if (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
          }
          if (!error && !existingUser) {
            bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, (error: string, salt: string) => {
              if (error) {
                throw new Error(error);
              }
              bcrypt.hash(password, salt, (error: string, hash: string) => {
                if (error) {
                  throw new Error(error);
                } else {
                  const newUser = new UserModel({
                    username,
                    password: hash,
                  });

                  newUser.save((error: string, user: User) => {
                    if (error) {
                      throw new Error(error);
                    } else {
                    }
                  });
                }
              });
            });
          }
        },
      );

      if (user) {
        throw new Error('That username is already in use!');
      } else {
        return {
          message: 'Registration successful!',
        };
      }
```